# svcutil not generating fault

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have received a wsdl from a java webservice team and when I try to generate c# proxy class using svcutil, it gives me an error on faults and doesn't generate those. I get the below error.

> Warning: Fault named ProvApiException in operation put cannot be
>   imported.      Unsupported WSDL, the fault message part must reference
>   an element.  This fault message does not reference an element. If you
>   have edit access to the WSDL document,  you can fix the problem by
>   referencing a schema element using the 'element' attribute.

I looked up the error and changed 'type' to 'element'. I also used /useSerializerForFaults option when generating the class, still no luck. It keeps giving me other errors. What should I edit in the wsdl to generate the faults? Also, any other option I should use in svcutil?

```
<complexType name="ProvApiException">
<sequence>
 <element name="errorCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="message" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="rootCause" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
```